# Swagger UI implementation via WebApplicationInitializer class

Tags: swagger

I am using spring 4.1.6 release version on was 8.5 for jackson jersery rest service. This has no web.xml. it is done thro WebApplicationInitializer class.Now i would like to implement swagger UI, I googled and didnt find any examples that fit my exact scenario. everyone is providing examples that is for rest controller thro spring mvc. i would like to know how to do it thro jackson jersey in spring4. please advise

Comment: used spring MVC , trigged swagger-ui that comes with swagger2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Bean
public SwaggerConfig swaggerConfig(){
    return new SwaggerConfig();
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
}
```

using this swagger-ui is enabled with spring MVC